# TypeError: $scope.array.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, reduce

I have 3 drop-down-lists that load attributes related to a page. These attributes are: instruments, style, scoring. The attributes are loaded from a service call.

Example using instruments:

```
  //Get Instruments
  $http.get('/api/Instrument/GetAllInstruments').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.instruments = data;
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.error = "An Error has occured while fetching Instruments!" + data;
  });
```

and the html:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        name="recordInstrument" 
        data-ng-model="recordInstrument" 
        required
        data-ng-options="i.ID as i.Description for i in instruments">
    <option value="">-- Choose an Instrument --</option>
</select>
```

A user can select a record from a list, and on a form, the values of that record are loaded. These values also include the attribute values that set the selected value for the drop-downs.

When the user clicks the record, a, "edit" function gets called. The function calls a service that gets the record, then it does an if statement to determine if the record attribute array is not empty. If the attribute array is not empty then it does a forEach loop on the array, sets the ng-model, in this case **"$scope.recordInstrument"** so that the selected default value is set for the record's drop-down. If the array is empty, then it set the ng-model to 0, to reset the drop-down to the no record selected value "Choose an instrument".

Here is that piece of code:
      //Edit Store Page
      $scope.edit = function () {

```
      if (this.page.SPPreambleID === null || this.page.SPPreambleID === 0) {
          this.page.SPPreambleID = -1;
      }

      $http.get('/api/StorePage/GetStorePage?StorePageID=' +
        this.page.StorePageID +
        '&SPPreambleID=' +
        this.page.SPPreambleID).success(function (data) {

            $scope.updateShow = true;
            $scope.addShow = false;
            $scope.newpage = data;

            if (data.SPAttributeRefID.length > 0) {

                angular.forEach($scope.newpage.SPAttributeRefID, function (attribute, index) {

                    if (attribute == 1) {

                        $scope.instruments = $scope.instruments.reduce(function (result, instrument) {
                            result[instrument.ID] = instrument;
                            return result
                        }, {});

                        $scope.recordInstrument = $scope.instruments[data.AttributeID[0]].ID;
                    };

                    if (attribute == 2) {

                        $scope.style = $scope.styles.reduce(function (result, style) {
                            result[style.ID] = style;
                            return result
                        }, {});
                        $scope.recordStyle = $scope.styles[data.AttributeID[1]].ID;
                    };

                    if (attribute == 3) {
                        $scope.scoring = $scope.scorings.reduce(function (result, scoring) {
                            result[scoring.ID] = scoring;
                            return result
                        }, {});
                        $scope.recordScoring = $scope.scorings[data.AttributeID[2]].ID;
                    };
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.recordInstrument = 0;
                $scope.recordStyle = 0;
                $scope.recordScoring = 0;
            }
        }).error(function () {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Editing this Store Page!" + data;
        });
  }
```

The code above was working before I put the if line: 
    if ($scope.newpage.SPAttributeRefID.length > 0) {
    ...
    }

The reason I added the if to check the array's length was because some records do not have drop down attributes, and if I was coming from a previous record that it had values, then the drop downs will stay with those values from the record before.

After I added the if, I started getting the error pointing to the reduce function and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would like to ask for help trying to resolve this issue.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using .reduce anymore. 
I changed the code to use a for loop after posting a new question and getting a working answer: [JavaScript: flatten an array without using reduce library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964205/javascript-flatten-an-array-without-using-reduce-library/39964285)

Here is the code snippet that replaces the reduce function:

```
if (attribute == 1) {

    var arrInstruments = $scope.instruments;
    var arrLength = arrInstruments.length;
    var result = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        result[arrInstruments[i].ID] = arrInstruments[i];
    }
    $scope.recordInstrument = result[$scope.newpage.AttributeID[0]].ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is here.

```
});
// you have a closing bracket missing
    }else {
        $scope.recordInstrument = 0;
    }
}).error(function () {
    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Editing this Store Page!" + data;
});
```

Fixed

```
});
  };  // added a close bracket
    }else {
        $scope.recordInstrument = 0;
    }
}).error(function () {
    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Editing this Store Page!" + data;
});
```

Comment: I think I pasted my code incorrectly and removed a few lines I should not when aiming to make it smaller before posting it. I updated the code for the edit function, so you can see that if I add that semi colon the code will break leaving the else out of the condition.

Comment: @erasmocarlos ahh yeah.. my mistake. Looking again on this line,       }).error(function ()  it appears to me that the ) is trying to close when it shouldn't be.      }.error(function ()  may be the fix.

Comment: That ")." before the "error(function...", is part of the "this.page.SPPreambleID).success(function (data) {..." - if I remove it, the code breaks.

Comment: @erasmocarlos ahh i see. Sorry I wasn't any help. Learned something in the process.

Comment: @erasmocarlos i cant give up sorry, been looking at it more. Could it be you need  if (.data > 0) to be followed by an else if rather than an if?  Since it was working before that, and how i visualize that the if followed by if would not catch.

Comment: which line are you referring to?

Comment: if (data.SPAttributeRefID.length > 0), followed by an else if rather than an if.

Comment: Sorry I just saw it goes into a for each.