# JavaScript: flatten an array without using reduce library

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a nested array named $scope.instruments, its contents are:

**collapsed:**

[image]

**expanded:**

[image]

I also have an object:

[image]

This object contains 2 arrays: AttributeID and SPAttributeRefID.

Currently I am flattening the $scope.instruments array using reduce function:

```
$scope.instruments = $scope.instruments.reduce(function (result, instrument) {
    result[instrument.ID] = instrument;
    return result
}, {});
```

Then I access the AttributeID of the object and assign it to a variable like this:

```
$scope.recordInstrument = $scope.instruments[data.AttributeID[0]].ID;
```

I would rather use a different method to obtain the same result. I read that an array can be flatten using a for loop, that it is a more efficient method of doing it. Unfortunately, what I have tried so far, is not giving me the same results.

```
var arrInstruments = $scope.instruments;
var arrLength = arrInstruments.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    console.log(arrInstruments[i]);                                
}
```

Can someone give me a hand converting the code that uses the reduce function to use a loop and have the same result in the assignment of AttributeID?

Many thanks.

Comment: `reduce` is not a library and not inefficient either. Why not just use your working solution?

Comment: Your screenshots don't show a nested array. You seem to be confused by the console representation of large arrays. There is no need to flatten anything here (but notice that your `reduce` code isn't even flattening anything either, rather it is building an ID lookup table).

Comment: You're not flattening, you're really creating a new object with the values from the original array. I agree with Bergi, keep what you have.

Comment: I understand, and I am ok keeping the in place solution. The problem I am having I explained in a different question, but I have not been able to get much help to correct it. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962933/typeerror-scope-array-reduce-is-not-a-function/39963229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do what you are looking for:

```
var arrInstruments = $scope.instruments;
var arrLength = arrInstruments.length;
var result = {}
for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    result[arrInstruments[i].ID] = arrInstruments[i];
}
// the result variable contains what you want.
```

> However I really don't understand why you would want that.

This screenshot you took:
[image]

Is **not** a multidimensional array. It's only the way your console show you a very large array (so it will not need to "draw" everything).

Comment: Thank you Dekel. How can by using that loop, do an assignment like the one on my original code: $scope.recordInstrument = $scope.instruments[data.AttributeID[0]].ID;

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not so sure I understand the question.

Comment: I understand that the console puts the array that way because it is too long. I am trying to set the value of a drop down menu. $scope.newpage is the record. $scope.instruments are all the values that populate the dropdown menu. When the record enters edit mode, I need to use the record's AttributeID value, to set the $scope.instruments array.

Comment: Never mind. I got it now. I did: $scope.recordInstrument = result[$scope.newpage.AttributeID[0]].ID;